# Spring Boot - Injecting application properties into a Util class variable

Tags: java, spring-boot, dependency-injection

I would like to ask a question as per title.

I have a util class such as follows:

```
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
public class ServiceUtils {

    @Value("${dummy}")
    public static String SOME_VAR;

    @Value("${dummy}")
    // Baeldung says that it's not possible to inject props to static vars
    public void setSomeVar(String var) {
       SOME_VAR = var;
    }
}
```

When I launch the application, and debug, the above variable `SOME_VAR` comes as `null` :(

I am aware that I am using this in a Util class, which is an antipattern, I think.

Could someone help me understand what I need to correct to get this to work?

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spring does not allow you to inject values in static variables. Use a non static instead.

If it has to be static, do something like this:

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class ServiceUtils {

    public static String SOME_VAR;

    @Value("${dummy}")
    public void setSomevar(String value) {
        SOME_VAR= value;
    }

}
```

Comment: SonarQube doesn't accept this

Answer (score 0):

```
@Service
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
public class ServiceUtils {

    private static String SOME_VAR;

    @Value("${dummy}")
    public void setSomeVar(String var) {
       this.SOME_VAR = var;
    }
}
```

Try to assign the value with `this` like you generally do in a setter.

Comment: I am not sure what difference you're referring to by `ServiceUtils.SOME_VAR` and `SOME_VAR` ...

Comment: @ha9u63ar : I am telling you to use `this` keyword... I have updated my code above. You can use that and check if u can see the desired result.  But remember this is only a workaround and not a very efficient way to set a non final static variable like this. There are some other really good approaches.